# SQL For XML PATH - Redundant xmlns throughout result and how to return a node with an attribute AND value

Tags: sql, xml, namespaces

Removing all the extraneous information from my initial posting and focusing on two items:

The majority of my data is just `<element>value</element>` but certain parts call out these namespace prefixes:

```
<componentList>
    <InstantiatedBillingRateComponent>
        <definition xsi:type="PSPM">
          ...
        </definition>
```

Looking at this as a model -
[How to return XML from SQL Server 2008 that is structured with multiple selections sharing a common parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260156/how-to-return-xml-from-sql-server-2008-that-is-structured-with-multiple-selectio)

Select BillRateType as "@xsi:type"
...
for xml path('definition'),type,elements

which gave me the error:
    XML name space prefix 'xsi' declaration is missing for FOR XML column name '@xsi:type'.

So I did some research on the WITH xmlnamespaces clause and added this to the beginning of the query:
WITH xmlnamespaces ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd )

I received no error but got this:

```
<definition xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="PSPM">
```

and received both xmlns: declarations ALL throughout the entire result (looks like every nested level at the XML PATH or Root if called out)

Problem 1: How can I get rid of all the xmlns (except the top level)

Problem 2: If my column called BillCat has the value COBRA how do I achieve this output?

```
<billingCategory>
    <ID xsi:type="xsd:string">COBRA</ID>
    <ID xsi:type="xsd:string">BillingCategory</ID>
</billingCategory>
```

Update: For this problem 2 I am getting closer - I'm unsure how to mix the element attributes and values together.

If I execute this:

```
WITH xmlnamespaces ('...://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi, '...://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd )
select 
    top 1
    'xsd:string' as "@xsi:type"
    ,BillCat
from
    ##chris_global
for xml path('ID'),type,elements,root('billingCategory')
```

I get:

```
<billingCategory xmlns:xsd="....://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="...://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ID xsi:type="xsd:string">
    <BillCat>COBRA</BillCat>
  </ID>
</billingCategory>
```

but i want:

```
<billingCategory>
    <ID xsi:type="xsd:string">COBRA</ID>
    <ID xsi:type="xsd:string">BillingCategory</ID>
</billingCategory>
```

I keep looking for query samples that show element with an attribute AND element value like above but cannot find one.

Update -

I found something that seems to work from: [can't post]

```
WITH xmlnamespaces ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd )
select 
    top 1
    'xsd:string' as "@xsi:type"
    ,BillCat as 'text()'
from
    ##chris_global
for xml path('ID'),type,elements,root('billingCategory')
```

gave me:

```
<billingCategory xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ID xsi:type="xsd:string">COBRA</ID>
</billingCategory>
```

So I guess I'm just looking for ways to remove the redundant xmlns from everything (short of parsing it out after the fact)